# Laravel putting 2 form values together and checking if their unique

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have recently started using Laravel5.2 and I wanted to know if their is a way to actually check if 2 form values are unique? I can do this with one but I have a form input value for First Name and one for Second name, what I want to do is something like below..

```
$fullName = $firstName . ' ' . $secondName;
//check if $fullName is unique
```

I mean I would love to have just one form value that you can enter booth first and second name into but I feel there is too much checking to actually check if theres only 2 words (2 names) in the form input.

So is there an easy way to check if firstName and secondName put together are unique.. such as below

say my first name was John and my second name was Smith, how could I check that "John Smith" was unique in the database under the "username" column? (1 column).

Comment: is your username field contains spaces ?

Comment: From your example above you included a space between firstname and second name , should I assume it's mistake since I understand you want username to be firstnamesecondname

Comment: And secondly what happens if someone enters a third name so you also wanna concatenated it?

Comment: Thirdly have you  considered the fact that lots o different  people have same surname and firstname

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Validator` to check it:

```
$arr = ['username'=>'John Smith'];
$rules = ['username'=>'unique:users'];
$message = ['username.unique'=>'Type your error here']; //new
//$validator = Validator::make($arr,$rules);
$validator = Validator::make($arr,$rules, $message);
if ($validator->fails()) {
     return $validator->messages();
}
```

Comment: Using your code with a few modifications I got it to work, although all the page displays is "{"username":["The username has already been taken."]}" is there any way to get it to display as an actual error? like the other errors..

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullName = $firstName . ' ' . $secondName;

if(DB::table('users')-> where('username',$fullName)->first()){
  return ('Its repeated');
}else{
  return('its unique');
}
```

if you have a model just change:

```
DB:table()
```

for your model, something like:

```
Users::where('username',$fullName)->first();
```